# How do I fix ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (2,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,2) error?

Tags: numpy

I am trying to train a neural network but I am stuck at this point where I should get and (2,1) array but the code keeps bringing me a (2,2) array.

Trying to transpose the matrix or making the (1,) array as scalar (v[0]) just didn't work.

This is a sample of the code I am having trouble with:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.3],[-0.1]])
b = np.zeros(a.shape)
c=np.array([ 0.5249765])
d=np.array([ 0.4850045,   0.45512111])
y = np.array([ 0.4])
error = y - c 
f= error * c * (1 - c)

b+=f[0]*d.T
```

The result I was expecing was

```
b = [-0.0151157 -0.0141844]
```

but I keep getting

```
b = [[-0.0151157    -0.0141844]
[-0.0151157 -0.0141844]]
```

Comment: You construct `b` with the same shape as `a` at the very beginning.  If you want a different shape, construct one.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`b=f[0]*d.T`

instead, otherwise you are broadcasting the addition of a (2,2) array with a (2,) array